# searching with Sphinx using bootstrap-theme

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

I cloned from author's https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme and finished all configuration.  Everything looks fine, except when you use the search function, it will display `Searching...` and nothing happened.

My python version is 3.9.1, sphinx-quickstart 3.4.3. And

```sh
$ pip freeze
alabaster==0.7.12
Babel==2.9.0
bcrypt==3.2.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==4.0.0
cryptography==3.3.1
docutils==0.16
fabric==2.5.0
idna==2.10
imagesize==1.2.0
invoke==1.5.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
packaging==20.8
paramiko==2.7.2
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.7.4
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.5
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
Sphinx==3.4.3
sphinx-bootstrap-theme==0.7.1
sphinxbootstrap4theme==0.6.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
urllib3==1.26.2
```

**UPDATE**:

It was solved by adding `language_data.js` to be loaded in `conf.py`.  Please see my comments

Comment: Check Developer Tools in the browser and see if the required JavaScript loads or 404s. You might not have the `conf.py` configured correctly to copy static assets to the build directory.

Comment: Error Msg from dev tool! The searchtools.js  line 158 var stemmer = new Stemmer();  Stemmer is not defined!    Uncaught ReferenceError: Stemmer is not defined!

Comment: If you want to use the theme you don't have to clone it, just use `pip install sphinx_bootstrap_theme`. See here [sphinx-bootstrap-theme installation](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme#installation) or here [HTML theming](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html). If you are really trying to clone the repository to do some development on it, then I think your question needs to include more details (the first comment gives some excellent advice.)

Comment: `pip install sphinx-bootstrap-theme` will cause the same problem.  Also, I found that using `pip install --upgrade` will cause some theme's search to fail.  I am just a user using sphinx to document my work.  I like bootstrap theme, but it looks like I have to wait for this problem be resolved by somebody.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: get a copy of language_data.js and and add these lines into  conf.py,     
 html_js_files = [
    'js/language_data.js',
], then search function works.  Why language_data.js was not loaded just like the other themes, is beyond my knowledge to fix it.

Comment: @AlexLai hello, if the answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the green check mark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: The problem was solved, but I don't know "the green check mark on the left side of the answer" .  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8623). Make sure you install the latest versions of Sphinx and use a git checkout of the [PR](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/pull/213). Give the maintainer feedback on the PR.